# динамическое обновление css

Tags: php, ajax

Есть такой код:

```
  <nav>
    <div class="name">Законопроекты</div>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) { ?>
    <ul>
      <a id="exit" href="#"><li>Выход</li></a>
    </ul>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <ul>
      <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#login", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Вход</li></a>
      <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#register", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Регистрация</li></a>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </nav>
```

То есть когда человек залогинен видно одно, когда нет - другое. Логин происходит без перезагрузки страницы, от чего данное меню меняется только после принудительного обновления страницы. Как сделать так, чтобы меню менялось моментально без перезагрузки в зависимости от наличия данных в сессии php?

Comment: Перерисовать элемент после запроса.

Comment: знать бы еще как это сделать))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, как это сделать.

**Вариант первый**:

1. Два стиля *CSS* - например, *signIn* && *notSignIn*.
2. В *HTML* коде заранее выводите два варианта (залогинен/не залогинен) и применяете к нему свои стили.

Напримеp:

**CSS**:

```
.signIn{
visibility: visible;
//other styles
}

.notSignIn{
visibility:collapsed; //or hidden
//other styles
}
```

**HTML & PHP**:

```
  <nav>
<div class="name">Законопроекты</div>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) { ?>
<ul class="notSignIn">
  <a id="exit" href="#"><li>Выход</li></a>
</ul>
<ul class="signIn">
  <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#login", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Вход</li></a>
  <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#register", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Регистрация</li></a>
</ul>
<?php } else { ?>
<ul class="signIn">
  <a id="exit" href="#"><li>Выход</li></a>
</ul>
<ul class="notSignIn">
  <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#login", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Вход</li></a>
  <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#register", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Регистрация</li></a>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Потом после *Ajax* запроса, Вы просто подменяете классы для Ваших `ul`.
Классы можно назвать `visible` и `notVisible` соответсвенно. Или вообще сделать один класс `visible`:

```
.visible{
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

а к элементам применить `visibility:hidden`

**Вариант второй**:

На стороне бэкенда (тот скрипт, где Ваш *Аjax* "логинит" пользователя), сделать примерно следующее:

```
<?php 
/*
* Check auth
* $isAuth = **auth result**(true/false)
*/
if($isAuth){
   return 
      "<ul><a id="exit" href="#"><li>Выход</li></a></ul>";
} else {
   return 
      "<ul>
           <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#login", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}'href="javascript:;"><li>Вход</li></a>
           <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#register", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Регистрация</li></a>
      </ul>"
}
```

В *JS* (*JQuery* же используете?):

```
success: function(data) { //часть JQuery Ajax call'a 
    $('#authWrap').html(data);
},
```

Код *HTML/PHP* страницы:

```
<nav>
  <div class="name">Законопроекты</div>
  <div id="authWrap">
   <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) { ?>
      <ul>
         <a id="exit" href="#"><li>Выход</li></a>
      </ul>
   <?php } else { ?>
      <ul>
         <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#login", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Вход</li></a>
         <a data-fancybox data-options='{"src": "#register", "touch": false, "toolbar" : false, "smallBtn" : false}' href="javascript:;"><li>Регистрация</li></a>
      </ul>
   <?php } ?>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Таким образом, при вызова *Ajax* функции в зависимости от результата Вы будете подменять содержимое `<div id="authWrap"></div>`.

Полезные ссылки:

1. [Замена](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_html-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) содержимого `div'a` с помощью *JQuery*;
2. [Замена](https://devionity.com/ru/courses/js-fundamentals-and-jquery/js-using-dom-changing-elements-accessing%20styles) содержимого `div'a` **без** *JQuery*;
3. [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) функция JQuery на англ. (оф. документация);
4. [Ajax](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) функция JQuery на русском.